# How can you launch fragments with supportFragmentManager purely in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

Can we still use fragments purely in compose?(The activity as well as the fragments having compose views) What I mean is how can you launch the fragments with supportFragmentManager?

Since the old way required I make a container like a frameLayout and pass the id to the fragment manager , allowing it to load the fragments in the container. With Compose how do I do that?

I researched on the matter and all I am getting is Navigation controller and Nested navigation graphs.

Comment: `How can you launch the fragments with supportFragmentManager?` this is your actual question, not `Are Fragments still a thing with JetPack Compose?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JetPack compose we have to use Navigation graphs, Fragments are no longer necessary:
https://youtu.be/FIEnIBq7Ups?si=UpFc_d2igYsfcC97